# Does anyone have the source for Sitefinity MVC Store Sample?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitefinity

Sitefinity MVC Store Sample use to be downloadable from the following:

http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/team-blog/2012/07/19/sitefinity_mvc_store_sample_website_project

However, the link is dead. **I already posted this to Sitefinity's forum and there response was that it was no longer available.**

Answer (score 0):

This repository contains samples related to Project Feather.

https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather-samples

Related Repositories

feather - This repository contains the core infrastructure related to the Feather project.

feather-widgets - This repository contains custom MVC widgets which are part of the Feather project.

feather-packages - This repository contains front-end packages for the Feather project.